# code chrome extension to override newtab css/js

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I think chrome forbids content script for chrome:// and chrome_url_overrides forces you to redirect newtab all together.

How can you inject css/js to newtab with a chrome extension?

Comment: You can't. See [chrome content scripts and newtab](//stackoverflow.com/q/45659294)

Answer (score -3):

You will need a theme extension for that.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/themes

Comment: It won't run a content script, which is what the OP needs.